# Problema de peso compilando con WebPack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Amigos, estoy trabajando sbre una aplicación con ReactJS usando es6. Empecé utilizando browserify para la conversión y compilación de es6 a es5. Pero me dí cuenta que mi archivo "bundle" luego de la transformación pesa 1.3mb, lo cual logicamente es **demasiado peso**. Mi carpeta src con *todos los script en es6 tan solo pesa 200kb*. En principio, pensé que *browserify* me estaba incluyendo o bien todas las dependencias (incluyendo unas que no necesitara) o que me estaba repitiendo los archivos. Esto porque como sabrán, en es6 debo usar líneas como

```
import Config from .'/config.js';
```

Para la inclusión de archivos que necesite y esto, a su vez lo hago en cada archivo. Por tanto, decidí cambiarme a **webPack** pues leí que este se encargaba de analizar lo que incluia y precisamente evitar la repetición de código (Para mi estas herramientas son nuevas). Pero **mi archivo compilado sigue teniendo un peso de 1.3mb**
Acá agrego mi archivo *dummy* de browserify

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './js/src/index.js',
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },
    "plugins":[
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules|libs/,

                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

Con eso generé un archivo map y hay archivos que me aparecen multiples veces, con lo cual corroboro que ese es el motivo por el que pesa tanto el archivo bundle. **¿Alguien tiene idea como puedo solucionar eso?**

En cuanto a la estructura de desarrollo, estoy usando React y React-router.
Por tanto, tengo un archivo index.js donde incluyo todos los archivos "routes" para registrar las rutas y luego tengo un archivo .jsx por cada ruta, en donde importo los archivos que pueda necesitar.

**Actualización**

Leyendo en documentación, recomiendan que se use el *include* y no el *exclude* en los loaders. por tanto intenté probando de la siguiente forma:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './js/src/index.js',
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    "plugins": [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                /*  exclude: [
                 NPM_DIR,
                 BOWER_DIR
                 ],
                 */
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                },
                include: [

                    path.join(__dirname, 'src/Clases'),
                    path.join(__dirname, 'src/components'),
                    path.join(__dirname, 'src/elements')
                ]

            }
        ]
    },
};
```

Pero haciendo ese ajuste, me da un error como si no reconociera los presets, arroja el siguiente error :

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (129:12)
```

Esa linea es donde empieza el metodo render de react, para ello están incluidos los presets en el segmento *query*, me habia pasado antes y lo solucioné así y ahora usando el key *include* vuelve a suceder.

Muchas gracias a quien pueda colaborarme ya que aun no veo luz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hice un [artículo en Medium](https://medium.com/@martiuh/webpack-bundle-para-producci%C3%B3n-312556bb2d9a#.elizr29f3) (que voy a copy-pastear aquí) sobre el `bundle` en produción, aunque ya no me quedó claro si en el `bundle` vas a agregar `react` o no. Yo lo que hago para economizar, es lo siguiente:

Antes de aplicarlo es necesario instalar los plugins para babel

`$ npm -i -D babel-plugins-transform-react-inline-elements babel-plugins-transform-react-constant-elements`

que sólo se deben de utilizar en producción, después modificas tu `webpack.config.js` para que pueda utilizar la `$NODE_ENV=production`, el archivo que yo uso es muy parecido a este

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
//En lugar de usar un archivo .babelrc, agregamos la configuración de babelQuery aquí
var babelQuery = {presets: ["react", "es2015"], plugins:[]};
var webpackConfig = {
  entry: './app/mainEntry.js',
  output: {
    path: "./public",
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
      loaders:[
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader:"babel",
        //BORRAME: Agregamos la babelQuery 
        query: babelQuery
      }
      ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  }
}
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  //El SourceMap más simple que se puede hacer, sin columnas de mapeo, sino simple líneas
  webpackConfig.devtool = 'cheap-module-source-map'
  // Este plugin es para que todos los módulos de node_modules se lean con la variable NODE_ENV = production
  // y no manden las alertas de desarrollo
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    }
  })
  );
  //Ignoramos ayudas para IE8
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    compress: {
      screw_ie8: true
    }
  })
  );
  /*
  transform-react-inline-elements
  Esto sólo es necesario si utilizamos la forma
  class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <h1>Soy App </h1>
      )
    }
  }
  Ya que hace una versión optimizada del código mucho mejor que React.createClass
  transform-react-constant-elements
  Reduce los llamados a React.createElement, evita repeticiones
  */
  babelQuery.plugins.push("transform-react-inline-elements","transform-react-constant-elements");
}
module.exports = webpackConfig
```

Si utiizas `babel` para otras cosas (como en mi caso lo utilizo con Express) entonces tienes que quitar todas las `babelQuery` del código de arriba y utilizar en tu archivo `.babelrc` la siguiente línea:

```
... ,
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": ["transform-react-constant-elements","transform-react-inline-elements"]
    }
  }
```

Ya para terminar tienes que correr como puso [@Guz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/26302/guz) tienes que correr webpack con -p para que `react` quite todas las alertas de desarrollo

```
$ NODE_ENV=production; webpack -p
```

Si de pura casualidad usas [`fish-shell`](http://fishshell.com/) como yo, entonces

```
$ set -x NODE_ENV production; webpack -p
```

Con la App que estoy haciendo actualmente con Redux, React-Router y React mi bundle de desarrollo pesa `1.19 MB` pero con la configuración de arriba se reduce a `288 KB` espero que esto aplique y solucione tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Eso no es nada, mi bundle de mi aplicación hecha en Vue.js pesa `2.6MB` y con source maps, pero en desarrollo. Hay varias razones para el que el tamaño del bundle aumente, pero principalmente se debe a **dependencias**. Por ejemplo, el paquete [`babel-standalone`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-standalone) tiene un peso de + `2MB`, [`lodash`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) más de `600KB` y [`react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react) al rededor de `600KB`. Si sumas ésto, tienes más de `3MB` en dependencias.

**Webpack**

Es importante que generes tus bundles para producción y no para desarrollo. Ésto puedes hacerlo definiendo un plugin para Webpack:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }
  })
]
```

Ahora ejecuta webpack:

```
webpack -p
```

Y obtendrás un bundle de mucho menos peso.

**Gzip**

Por lo general, en producción los estáticos se envían comprimidos mediante Gzip. Por ejemplo, si comprimes `lodash` obtendrás un peso muchísimo menor:

```
gz lodash.js
Original: 504040 bytes
Gzipped: 89746 bytes (17.81%)
```

---

Generando un bundle para producción y usango Gzip en tu servidor, lograrás grandes mejoras respecto al peso de tu bundle y así, una respuesta más rápida del servidor.

Comment: Yo tengo los archivos de React Aparte. No los comprimo. Y el problema es que es para una app con cordova y el emulador me da falla por el peso. Estuve documentandome y me dijeron que lo mejor es ver como bajarlo. Probaré con el plugin. Tambien haré un ajuste en la pregunta para que vea otro detalle que tengo.